# What is the tag mapping for entity recognition in nltk?

Tags: nltk, named-entity-recognition

When doing entity recognition using NLTK, one gets as a result a `Tree` with a bunch of words mapped to tags (eg. `Mark -> NNP`, `first -> JJ`, ...). It's not at all clear what all the tags stand for at first glance and I was unable to find any documentation about these tags in the `NLTK` docs.

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> sentence = "Mark and John are the first to work at Google from one years old in 39 years."
>>> print ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
(S
  (PERSON Mark/NNP)
  and/CC
  (PERSON John/NNP)
  are/VBP
  the/DT
  first/JJ
  to/TO
  work/VB
  at/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Google/NNP)
  from/IN
  one/CD
  years/NNS
  old/JJ
  in/IN
  39/CD
  years/NNS
  ./.)
```

I ended up looking into the source code to get the mapping. Posting in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag mapping according to [nltk source](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/app/chunkparser_app.py#L52)

```
  'CC':   'Coordinating conjunction',   'PRP$': 'Possessive pronoun',
  'CD':   'Cardinal number',            'RB':   'Adverb',
  'DT':   'Determiner',                 'RBR':  'Adverb, comparative',
  'EX':   'Existential there',          'RBS':  'Adverb, superlative',
  'FW':   'Foreign word',               'RP':   'Particle',
  'JJ':   'Adjective',                  'TO':   'to',
  'JJR':  'Adjective, comparative',     'UH':   'Interjection',
  'JJS':  'Adjective, superlative',     'VB':   'Verb, base form',
  'LS':   'List item marker',           'VBD':  'Verb, past tense',
  'MD':   'Modal',                      'NNS':  'Noun, plural',
  'NN':   'Noun, singular or masps',    'VBN':  'Verb, past participle',
  'VBZ':  'Verb,3rd ps. sing. present', 'NNP':  'Proper noun, singular',
  'NNPS': 'Proper noun plural',         'WDT':  'wh-determiner',
  'PDT':  'Predeterminer',              'WP':   'wh-pronoun',
  'POS':  'Possessive ending',          'WP$':  'Possessive wh-pronoun',
  'PRP':  'Personal pronoun',           'WRB':  'wh-adverb',
  '(':    'open parenthesis',           ')':    'close parenthesis',
  '``':   'open quote',                 ',':    'comma',
  "''":   'close quote',                '.':    'period',
  '#':    'pound sign (currency marker)',
  '$':    'dollar sign (currency marker)',
  'IN':   'Preposition/subord. conjunction',
  'SYM':  'Symbol (mathematical or scientific)',
  'VBG':  'Verb, gerund/present participle',
  'VBP':  'Verb, non-3rd ps. sing. present',
  ':':    'colon',
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on the answer of @Kevin S Lin. [POS tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) or Part-of Speech tagging refers to:

> the process of marking up a word in a text (corpus) as corresponding to a particular part of speech, based on both its definition and its context—i.e., its relationship with adjacent and related words in a phrase, sentence, or paragraph. A simplified form of this is commonly taught to school-age children, in the identification of words as nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, etc.

More information on each particular tag can be found using the:

```
nltk.help.upenn_tagset()
```

Although the `tagsets` dataset needs to be downloaded. More on these matter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk).